# Data Cable Through Drywall

Tags: wiring, drywall, data-wiring, ethernet

The drywallers forgot to cut a hole for my ethernet cable.  There is a coil of it behind the drywall.  Any ideas how to get it through without cutting a huge hole in the wall???

Thank you!

Comment: Can you reach the coil if you cut the hole where you want your finished ethernet port?  If you can't you have options, if the baseboard isn't on make the hole low so the baseboard will cover it.  If baseboard is on you can use a fish tape assuming the cable is in the correct stud bay.

Answer (score 4):

- Cut a 2" x 4" hole.
- Pull the wire through.
- Install a [box eliminator](https://amzn.to/326a2GJ).
- Depending on what you are trying to do, either install a blank plate and route the cable around to where it needs to go, or install a plate with an RJ45 jack and cut the cable and attach it to the jack.

The worst result will be a blank plate for no apparent reason - but there are plenty of blank plates in buildings, so that is not a big deal.

Comment: +1 but don't cut the cable short - it's highly unlikely that you are at length limit, and it's just fine to have some extra back there in the wall, while it's utterly annoying to have not QUITE enough. So err on the side of more than you think you'll need.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Absolutely correct. Plus, unlike, 120V electric cable, having a bunch of it coiled when in use will produce no ill effects.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact that depends on how tightly its coiled and what grade ethernet the OP wants...

Comment: @Moo: if OP was running a datacenter in their house they wouldn't bother with having it behind drywall.

Comment: @whatsisname you vastly underestimate the number of IT professionals who want high speed wired connectivity in their home, for a variety of reasons.  The number of peeps buying high end kit for home use these days is eyeopening.

Comment: It also doesn't take much to want to have wired Ethernet instead of doing everything with WiFi. WiFi has come a long way in the last few years, but it still doesn't compare to a wired connection.

Comment: @Moo: more that you are overestimating how much some extra cable in the wall is going to influence, and a situation where a few percent less speed was critical wouldn't be a residential application.

Comment: @whatsisname Ive had a situation where a single kink beyond the acceptable bend radius in a cable was enough to kill the data rate by 90%, so always check the allowable bend radius when coiling - my comment above was not about extra cable, it was about the coiling of said cable.

Comment: @Moo Normal coiling shouldn't be a problem. As opposed to with electrical cable where normal coiling (i.e., not any bend radius issue) can have some serious heating effects.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact given the size of the hole being described in your answer (which I have no issues with), its quite possible that the coil will be in violation of the 1 inch radius minimum that Cat6 allows for in spec, hence my warning - if someone isnt aware there is a radius issue, they wont take care not to violate it.  This site is about giving good advice, and we are talking data cabling here, so warnings about the coiling is perfectly on topic - comparisons with electrical cabling coiling is a misnomer here because the issues to watch for are not the same.

Comment: @Moo Good point. My intention is to figure out where the cable is, cut the hole in front of it and then carefully pull the cable through. If you can do that by pulling an end rather than trying to grab a big coil and pull it through "as is" then there shouldn't be any bend radius issues.

Comment: @Moo you almost surely had a garbage cable then. I've had cables kinked and run over by office chairs over and over again and still be capable of saturating a 1G ethernet connection.

Comment: @whatsisname I give up discussing this with you - I've only been doing IT now for 25 years and have put in multiple home and office data centres, including running my own cabling, but yes, I know nothing.  Op and question poster, take whatsisnames advice, disregard mine entirely.